# Update only rows where cust_id is present in other table

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a query that will present a list of customers to be anonomized:

```
select cu_number into #_t
from customer
where cu_first_name is not null
```

I want to update last_name to " 'Anonomized' + sequence " and try this:

```
update customer
  set cu_last_name = 'Anonomized' + convert(varchar, cu_number)
where cu_number = (select * from #_t);
```

I get the following error, and can't seem to find a suitable way around this:

> "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Anyone with an idea on how to improve the subquery?

/Andreas

Comment: where cu_number IN (select * from #_t);

Comment: why do you need a temp table? why not do this `update customer set cu_last_name='Anonomized' + convert(varchar(<somelength>), cu_number) WHERE cu_first_name is not null`

Comment: Try using where exists instead of comparing cu_number using a select statement

Comment: I have simplified the question a bit. The reason I have a temporary table is because I need to be able to add conditions to the initial select, and I'm to lazy to replace in all the steps. At the time I have 15 updates going to different tables where 'cu_number' is a common denominator. (i.e. in table address ad_customer is the same as cu_customer).

@jarlh I will try 'IN' later. Seems like that should work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the answer was delivered in a comment, I thought I'd add it as an answer. Adding "IN" instead of "=" solved the issue I had.

```
where cu_number IN (select * from #_t);
```

Thank you, @Jarlh! And thank you to the rest as well for great tips going forward.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need temp table at all:

```
update customer set cu_last_name='Anonomized' + convert(char, cu_number)
where cu_first_name is not null
```

In `MySQL` you can not use `convert` function with `varchar` type.

For `Sql Server`:

```
update customer set cu_last_name='Anonomized' + convert(varchar(10), cu_number)
where cu_first_name is not null
```

Comment: OP's code looks like Transact-SQL to me. At the very list, `CONVERT(type, value)` is not a MySQL syntax, [which would be `CONVERT(value, type)` instead](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert).

Comment: I don't remember bu probably I have answered this question quickly before post was edit. or may be there was some comment which was deleted.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry. I have mixed my tags. I'm quite new to this and still learning. Thank you for your response!